# How to know what exact function throws exception (Java)?

Tags: java, exception, ioexception

I have two functions (`ServerSocket.accept()` and `Socket.setSoTimeOut()`) which are throwing IOException and SocketException which is extending IOException.

How can I know which function throw this exception if I'm catching IOException? 
Should I call these functions on separate try/catch blocks? Or there is a more proper way to do that?

Comment: [`exception.printStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace())

Comment: The stack trace will show the culprit. If you catch and log, use a log method with an Exception/Throwable parameter.

Comment: oops.. I can do that by catching both of them! BUT inheritors should be first. I did'nt know that the order is efects..

Comment: As a rule, *never* do `catch (IOException e) { /* nothing */ }`. The only time it's acceptable to do nothing is when you know the exception can never occur (this happens when using reflection), and even then it's probably better to rethrow a `RuntimeException` just in case.

Comment: I don't want to see at the log.. I want to close the socket and keep running..

Comment: @uriel Log it anyway. This is what logging libraries like `log4j` or `logback` are for – you can log recoverable stuff at different *levels* of importance. The library can then be configured to only log errors in regular use, but show warnings (which are appropriate for recoverable exceptions) and more detailed information during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about having two catch blocks, one for SocketException and the other one for IOException. You can then tell which method call failed by the catch block that gets executed.

Note: The catch block for SocketException should come first for the code to be valid and compile.

Comment: Hi.. If bot of function are throwing an IOException ex. there is a way to find out which function did the throwing?

Comment: In this scenario I think you might need to inspect the exception object itself, or possibly have separate try blocks for each method. Out of interest why do you need to do this? There might be other elegant ways of accomplishing what you are trying to do.

Comment: And another thing is, will Socket.setSoTimeOut() ever throw an actual IOException? I doubt this is a possible scenario.

Comment: Actully, I did'nt thing about that.. But I asked in general, is I've two functions which are throwing the same exception object, how can I find out which function cause the exception. Did you tell anything about inspecting the object itself?.. what you mean? how can I do that?

Comment: For the problem in the above question, two separate catch blocks should suffice but in general, if two methods throw the exact same exception, the solution that comes to mind is the method exception.getStackTrace() and iterating through the stack elements. But this is rather dirty and shouldn't be done in normal practice. Refactoring your code and approaching the goal differently should suffice in addressing your needs more elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Exception object's getStackTrace() method.

Answer (score 0):

I would revert the question to "do I need separate logic to be run in case of which method call raised an exception"? If the answer is yes, then two `try / catch` blocks are indeed needed.